# Customizing the welcome email in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss, wss, wss-3.0

I can customize the footer of the welcome email coming from SharePoint when a user is added to a site by editing the data name="ServerEmailFooter" element in core.en-US.resx.  The question is, can I get anything dynamic in there, like the email of the owner who added the user, or any owner of the site?

So far I've seen <GetVar> and <ListProperty> used in the resource file, but no idea how to figure out which vars are available.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you can't modify this mail.
BTW, modifying core.resx is not supported and will certainly be overwritten when you'll apply the next SP or CU.

Edited: Related blog post - http://blogs.msdn.com/anolan/archive/2008/01/07/is-it-possible-to-modify-sharepoint-email-notifications.aspx

Comment: There comes a time in every SharePoint developer's life when he (or she) realizes that sometimes you have to make unsupported changes to get things done. As long as you know the risks and are smart about it, it's not a big deal.  I am modifying the resx file (core.en-US.resx, not core.resx). My question is, are there any dynamic properties available to me in that context.

Also, the link you provided deals with Alters email, not welcome emails.

Comment: Actually, it deals with welcome email if you read it to the end.  
At the end, it also tells you where to look to have your answer. You'll have to use Reflector to see the "SendEmailInvitation" method.

Comment: You're right, I didn't look past the first part. However, the post seems to be completely missing the ServerEmailFooter, which is what's customizable in core.en-US.resx.